# Jupyter notebook is 3x slower when using spark-submit yarn-client instead of spark-submit local

Tags: pyspark, client, local, jupyter-notebook, hadoop-yarn

I am working on a Hadoop (Cloudera) Data Lake with:

- Spark 1.6.0
- Python 3.5.2
- IPython 4.1.1 (notebook server is 4.1.0)

I am executing the exact same code.

1. counting the number of entry on a 4M entries Hive table
2. counting the number of entry on a 70M entries Hive table
3. complex SQL query with many joins on Hive tables

I am trying to understand the difference in  between:

1. running the Hadoop cluster ("spark-submit --master yarn-cluster" using Oozie)
2. running the edge node of the Hadoop cluster ("spark-submit --master local")
3. using the Jupyter notebook  ("spark-submit --master yarn-client")
4. using the Jupyter notebook  ("spark-submit --master local")

Please find the tests below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  test                                | wall time code 1 | wall time code 2 | wall time code 3   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Oozie (spark-submit yarn-cluster)   |  14.50 s         | 010.69 s          |  085.74 s         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  edge node (spark-submit yarn-client)|  12.93 s         | 008.91 s          |  122.12 s         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  edge node (spark-submit local)      |  05.15 s         | 019.05 s          |  414.68 s         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Jupyter (spark-submit yarn-client)  |  15.30 s         | 145.77 s          |  986.71 s         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Jupyter (spark-submit local)        |  05.89 s         | 021.46 s          |  385.66 s         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For me it make sens to have result computer much faster when using YARN-cluster than when using the the edge node and API to access the data on the cluster. What I don't understand why using Jupyter Notebook I see a factor 2.5x between :

- using the Jupyter notebook  ("spark-submit --master yarn-client")
- using the Jupyter notebook  ("spark-submit --master local")

I would expect that with Jupyter notebook "spark-submit --master yarn-client" is faster than "spark-submit --master local".
What could explain such differences ?

Authentication steps and proxy translation and multi-users management behind JupyterHub ?

How can check what is the issue in our configuration ? Any doc on how to have the best setup ? It is nice to use Jupyter Notebook for quick data exploration so I would like to understand the differences.

My Spark settings are the following

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster 
--files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml 
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3/bin/python3 
--conf spark.ui.enabled=false 
--conf spark.yarn.security.tokens.hive.enabled=false 
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=6144 
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer 
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=snappy 
--conf spark.speculation=true 
--conf spark.shuffle.manager=sort 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=4 
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=10g 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=2 
--conf spark.executor.cores=4 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=20 
--conf spark.executor.memory=10g 
--conf spark.driver.memory=10g 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xms10g 
--conf spark.akka.frameSize=2047 
--conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2047mb 
testpyspark.py
```

Comment: Please don't mix up `yarn-cluster mode` _(i.e. the notebook starts a Spark launcher, which then starts a Spark driver on YARN, which then starts executors on YARN)_ and `running Spark on a Hadoop cluster in yarn-client mode`  _(i.e. the notebook starts a local Spark Driver, which then starts executors on YARN)_; also "edge" and "hedge" and not the same thing, biloute...

Comment: What are your Spark settings in `yarn-client` mode -- static number of containers (i.e. all YARN allocation latency is included in the iPython kernel startup time) or dynamic number (i.e. some YARN allocation latency is deferred to actual execution time)?

Comment: How many partitions in your dataframes? If you use just 1 executor, running multiple executors on YARN will bring no gain. And if you use many (and maybe too many) partitions/executors, how much data is transferred between executors at shuffle time? Shuffling in local mode is obviously much faster than using network (between nodes) and filesystem (for checkpointing of received data).

Comment: Note that Oozie does not necessarily use `yarn-client` mode; Oozie uses a dummy YARN container to launch Spark, but then Spark could use any mode. Conversely when you run Spark on an Edge Node you can set any mode, from `local` to `yarn-client` to `yarn-cluster` (although the last one makes no sense for interactive test-runs).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I fixed the typo with edge node in the table. I added an entry in the table when running `yarn-client` on the edge node. I tried to run with Oozie and `yarn-client` but it didn't work. Maybe it doesn't make sens. I am only working with Hadoop since few weeks.

Comment: My spark setting are the following:

Comment: I added my Spark settings above (I hope this is what you want). I used them for all tests (I know it probably doesn't really make sens when running on the edge node but the idea was to be able to compare `yarn-client` running from the edge node or from Jupyter notebook).

Comment: I have 15 partitions for a little bit more than one year of data (YYYY-mm). Since we are completely new in this area  we are just starting to compare things before doing the optimization.

Comment: For Oozie, I started to test things with a shell action and not a spark-action. The `spark-submit` above is exactly that is my shell script that I am executing with Oozie. I a trying to understanding things to be able to optimize them later. What I don't understand right now in the executing time with Jupyter notebook and spark-submit yarn-client. Do you think that the Sparks settings could be the reason ? Even if we the edge note and the same command line it works well.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about the `-Xms10g` -- the Java stack never grows that big, it's usually the heap that you have to bound... And I'm real puzzled about the lack of consensistency of these test runs (provided that the iPython kernel uses the same exact parameters that you set for `spark-submit`). Did you inspect the YARN logs in case there are strange errors followed by automatic retries, executors not starting in time because YARN does not have enough resources to launch enough of these HUGE containers (especially if speculative execution starts extra useless containers), etc?

Comment: ok, I will remove this option. Anway, I will need to review all of them and optimize then. Last time I looked at the log, I found some messages that could be related to this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17696 `ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver xxxxxxx disassociated! Shutting down.` We should have Spark 2.1 installed this week so I will retry. I will do more test and try to find what could be wrong in our setup/option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to Cloudera 5.8. There was a compatibility issue between the Python version that is executed in Jupyter and the HDFS Name Node.

The solution is to add in the kernel the PATH to python 2 on top of all the other paths that are needed for the kernel itself :

"PATH":"/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda2/bin/"

Comment: How to the path tot he Kernel? Where is the Kernel configuration file?